# ng2-ckeditor error Module not found & Metadata version mismatch for module

Tags: angular, npm-install

I am trying `ng serve` on my angular 4 project and I see this

```
ERROR in /var/www/penderie1/src/app/admin/admin.module.ts (20,32): Cannot find module 'ng2-ckeditor'.
ERROR in /var/www/penderie1/src/app/myaccount/myaccount.module.ts (6,32): Cannot find module 'ng2-ckeditor'.
ERROR in /var/www/penderie1/src/app/app.module.ts (6,32): Cannot find module 'ng2-ckeditor'.
ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve ng2-ckeditor relative to /var/www/penderie1/src/app/app.module.ts., resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/penderie1/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/penderie1/src/app/app.module.ts
    at syntaxError (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at simplifyInContext (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:212:44)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:448:24)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

I don't understand the issue as `ck-editor` is included correctly in my config files.
When I run `npm install ng-2-ckeditor --save` and run `ng serve` ,i  see this error

```
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /var/www/penderie1/node_modules/ng2-ckeditor/lib/ng2-ckeditor.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/penderie1/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/penderie1/src/app/app.module.ts
    at syntaxError (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at simplifyInContext (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:212:44)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (/var/www/penderie1/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:448:24)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
```

Comment: did you do npm install ?

Comment: did you run `npm install`?

Comment: yes, i did. I only see warning there. not the errors

Comment: run again `npm install ng2-ckeditor --save` and check

Comment: done, it is still same

Comment: See my edit, error is changed now

Comment: Install version 1.1.9 of ng2-ckeditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brother, it is a version issue. 
try updating 
your angular version from 4 to 5 if it is 4, or else try

```
try to use
"ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.9",
instead
"ng2-ckeditor": "^1.1.9",
```

Comment: that's good to hear if this helped please accept this as an answer which will also help others. happy coding..

Comment: Thanks changing version is helpful for me.

Answer (score 4):

Install version 1.1.9 of ng2-ckeditor. try `npm install ng2-ckeditor@1.1.9 --save`

Comment: Thanks changing version is helpful for me.